# How do I use generated code from @graphql-codegen to do a simple fetch of a single record?

Tags: typescript, graphql, code-generation, graphql-codegen

https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen

I have run through the getting started guide and now I have a generated code file that was built from an existing deployed federated graph. In there I have:

```
export type Query = {
  __typename?: 'Query';
  customerById: Customer;
  // not a complete list
```

OK, now I'd like to use that query to get a customer, say it's customer ID `5a5e5aca-5512-4fb7-bde4-03fadf88e777`. The docs [have me writing new GQL](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/guides/react-vue), e.g.:

```
const allFilmsWithVariablesQueryDocument = graphql(/* GraphQL */ 
 query allFilmsWithVariablesQuery($first: Int!) {
    allFilms(first: $first) {
      edges {
        node {
          ...FilmItem

... 

const { data } = useQuery(allFilmsWithVariablesQueryDocument, { variables: { first: 10 } })
```

Which makes it seem like I need local GQL to query my remote GQL?

But really I'd like to just write something like `const customer = runQuery(Queries.customerById, {id: '5a5e5aca-5512-4fb7-bde4-03fadf88e777' })`. [Which is much closer to what Zeus does](https://zeus.graphqleditor.com/page/getting-started.html) (see "Query with Zeus Chain Client" section).

I'd like to be able to get autocomplete in a query. Zeus has this, sort of, but there are some odd dependencies (global fetch, global Websocket) that put me off of it -- I don't want to have to correct generated code.

Is this a capability that @graphql-codegen has? or am I misunderstanding?  If it's possible to use that `Query:customerById` in a function, how?

Answer (score -1):

here Charly, working on GraphQL Code Generator.

I think that the [`typescript-generic-sdk`](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-generic-sdk) plugin might fit your needs.